# webpack dev server proxy implicitly using a wildcard

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the following in my config

```
        proxy: {
            "/conf": "http://localhost:8080",
            "/ws": {
                "target": "ws://localhost:8080",
                "ws": true
            }
        }
```

and am building a single page app where one of the routes is `/configuration`.

I cannot refresh the page on this URL without the request being proxied to the backend, which has no idea how to handle this. Is there someway to ensure on `/conf` is proxied and not, effectively `/conf*`